# How to collect results from physical machines like bio and chemical analyzers?

Tags: python, linux, windows, api

Stack Overflow community!
I was wondering what would be the best programming language for extraction laboratory test results from physical analyzers to software or website? And what's science behind this type of projects?

Answer (score 0):

So I've read an article and python is the best programming language since python is best for automation and since automation is really important for data science not only is it helpful it's also efficient.

Here's the link to the article: https://flatironschool.com/blog/data-science-programming-languages/

Hope this helped.

Comment: I was looking for a data science developer in Fiverr, and 3 of them who responded me have no clue about my task. The basic idea is that we run bio laboratory, so we use analyzers, and we want our website or software to be able to collect test results from physical analyzers. Some analyzers have their own software, but some of them print out an output to printer.